# How do I add session variable to view markup?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, session, razor

I am trying to add a session variable to html markup using MVC Razor, I tried this:

```
<div class="panel-body">
<p>It might suprise you to know that you can upgrade from @Session("CurrentProvider") to blah blah....</p>
</div>
```

I tried wrapping it in code tags and all sorts. How can I fix this?

Comment: I read that first - seemingly not the answer

Comment: Session is not a function, you should use it like `Session["CurrentProvider"]`

Comment: Might be that way in C#, but this is VB

Answer (score 0):

Seems the answer is to append with ToString

@Session("CurrentProvider").ToString